# traceback: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on this bot for a web scraping app.

```
import os
import booking.constanst as const
from selenium import webdriver 


class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    
    def __init__(self, driver_path=(r"C:\Users\Narsil\dev\seleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe")):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def land_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)
```

I get this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

I have tried to add the path to my enviromental variables, set the path of chromedrive and executed, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
```

This is not the right way to set the environment variable. Actually `webdriver` allows you to specific the path of chromedriver binary, so you don't need to make use of environment variable.

```py
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\Narsil\dev\seleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe")

class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    
    def __init__(self, driver_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__(executable_path=driver_path)
```

Besides, IMO composition is more suitable than inheritance to build page object in most cases. Here is the sample.

```py
class BasePageObject:
  def __init__(self, driver_path):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

class Booking(BasePageObject):
      def land_page(self):
        self.driver.get(const.BASE_URL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it works perfectly. Otherwise, I will check out the IMO composition.